# How can I set a single proxy for a requests session object?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the Python requests package to send http requests. I want to add a single proxy to the requests session object. eg.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {...} # Here I want to add a single proxy
```

Currently I am looping through a bunch of proxies, and at each iteration a new session is made. I only want to set a single proxy for each iteration.

The only example I see in the documentation is:

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
    "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

I've tried to follow this, but to no avail. Here is my code from the script:

```
# eg. line = 59.43.102.33:80
r = s.get('http://icanhazip.com', proxies={'http': 'http://' + line})
```

But I get an error:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse 59.43.102.33:80
```

How is it possible to set a single proxy on a session object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In fact, you are right, but you must ensure your defination of 'line', I have tried this , it's ok:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.get("http://www.baidu.com", proxies={'http': 'http://10.11.4.254:3128'})
<Response [200]>
```

Did you define the line like `line = ' 59.43.102.33:80'`, there is a space at the front of address.

Comment: There was a space at the beginning of each line. It's always the simplest things that trick me out the most lol. Thanks :)

Comment: Note: If you're using a proxy server e.g. squid, this isn't going to keep you using the same IP address. i.e. the subsequent `s.get` will use the original proxy/actual ip.

Answer (score 107):

In addition to @neowu' answer, if you would like to set a proxy for the lifetime of a session object, you can also do the following -

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': 'http://10.11.4.254:3128'}
s = requests.session()
s.proxies.update(proxies)
s.get("http://www.example.com")   # Here the proxies will also be automatically used because we have attached those to the session object, so no need to pass separately in each call
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @BugHunterUK

Comment: Many thanks! It's the better response for me. Use the proxies in ALL next requests

Comment: Strangely, when I set the proxies for the session like that, it fails for me (with `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))`), but if I pass the exact same dict to the `get` method, it works fine.

Comment: Ah, just found the issue - if you have other proxies defined in the environment, use `session.trust_env=False` to make sure your proxies defined for the session are not overridden by the environment (in my case, we use different proxies for different tasks).

Comment: if you're doing this chances are you're using a self signed certificate that will throw **[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]** to surpass that use **s.verify = False**

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways you can set proxies, apart from the solutions you have got so far:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    # either like this
    s.proxies = {'https': 'http://105.234.154.195:8888', 'http': 'http://199.188.92.69:8000'}
    # or like this
    s.proxies['https'] = 'http://105.234.154.195:8888'
    r = s.get(link)
```

Comment: hows this differ from `s.proxies.update(proxies)` in the answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may lead to an answer:

> urllib3.util.url.parse_url(url)
>   Given a url, return a parsed Url namedtuple. Best-effort is performed to parse incomplete urls. Fields not provided will be None.

retrived from https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html