# How do i change my location sending a request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.5

I need to send a request to get all cruise information from this web page:
https://www.ncl.com
Problem is that i am in Europe and i need the prices to be in US dollars. Somehow the page "knows" where i am and i cant get it to return currency other than EUR. Is there a way to do that programmatically?
So far my request is this:

```
session = requests.session()
headers = {
    "authority": "www.ncl.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/ca/en/search_vacations",
    "scheme": "https",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "referer": "https://www.ncl.com/ca/en/",
    "cookie":"AkaUTrackingID=5D33489F106C004C18DFF0A6C79B44FD; AkaSTrackingID=F942E1903C8B5868628CF829225B6C0F; UrCapture=1d20f804-718a-e8ee-b1d8-d4f01150843f; BIGipServerpreprod2_www2.ncl.com_http=61515968.20480.0000; _gat_tealium_0=1; BIGipServerpreprod2_www.ncl.com_r4=1957341376.10275.0000; MP_COUNTRY=us; MP_LANG=en; mp__utma=35125182.281213660.1481488771.1481488771.1481488771.1; mp__utmc=35125182; mp__utmz=35125182.1481488771.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); utag_main=_st:1481490575797$ses_id:1481489633989%3Bexp-session; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D37513E254394AD66-1292924EC7FC34CB%7C1544560775848%3B%20s_nr%3D1481488775855-New%7C1484080775855%3B; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20c%3DundefinedDirect%2520LoadDirect%2520Load%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; _ga=GA1.2.969979116.1481488770; mp__utmb=35125182; NCL_LOCALE=en-US; SESS93afff5e686ba2a15ce72484c3a65b42=5ecffd6d110c231744267ee50e4eeb79; ak_location=US,NY,NEWYORK,501; Ncl_region=NY; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1481488768465r0.23231006365903206",
    "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic QFRLLTVmZjIwN2YzLTlmOGUtNDk0MS05MjY2LTkxMjdiMTZlZTI5ZDpAVEstNWZmMjA3ZjMtOWY4ZS00OTQxLTkyNjYtOTEyN2IxNmVlMjlk"
}
session.headers.update(headers)
url = "https://www.ncl.com/ca/en/search_vacations?cruise=1&cruiseTour=1&cruiseHotel=1&cruiseHotelAir=1&flyCruise=1&numberOfGuests=4294953449&state=undefined&pageSize=10&currentPage=" + str(page_counter) + "&sortBy=Featured&autoPopulate=f&from=resultPage"
    page = session.get(url)
    cruise_results = page.json()
```

I really need to do that without using VPN tunnelling or proxies.
The cookie i am using was not the first i've tried. This one above, is the one ive got when i tunneled the connection and opened the page from USA. Didn't do the job so i guess the cookie is not involved. I'm still quite new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow the page "knows" where i am and i cant get it to return currency other than EUR.

You have to debug/experiment -- it's the server logic/code, which you don't know.

Most probably they detect your location by your IP address, then you need to use a proxy server.

It could also be, that the cookies you are using have some info which defines your user settings (for example I find in it `MP_COUNTRY=us;`).

Some sites use a special GET argument (for example `country=US`, or `region` or whatever), which overrides the country/region deduced from your IP -- look for it, maybe you have luck.

Comment: well, as i said, this is a cookie, properly generated from a visit via VPN tunnel. If it's the cookie, my need to work.

Comment: So, when you first did the request through the USA tunnel, the prices were in USD?

Comment: Yes. Problem is replicating this in the code when the program is run from Europe

Comment: I am afraid, you have no choice -- you must use tunnels or proxy servers. The IP datagram contains the sender's IP address -- you cannot tamper with it.

Comment: is there a way to programmatically send my request via proxy service?

Comment: Yes, `requests` library supports this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837839/how-can-i-set-a-single-proxy-for-a-requests-session-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely determining your location through your IP address. I do not believe there is a way to change this programmatically as it is provided by your ISP. You will need to set up a VPN or proxy to do this. Why do you say you need to do it without a VPN? They're really easy to set up if that's the worry.

Comment: Program will be run from different locations and prefer all those settings to be done in code. Is there a way to send only a request via proxy? Maybe set up that in code?

Comment: I don't believe so.