# using a proxy for whole session in requests module

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am using burp suite as a local proxy to see the requests made.

```
import requests
p = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(p)
res = s.get('http://httpbin.org')
```

I want to define proxy once for whole session. Using proxy every time like:

```
res = s.get('http://httpbin.org', proxies=p)
```

works fine but just using  `s.proxies.update(p)` doesn't work. Any thoughts? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839005/7653529) but no help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you want to do.. According to the requests documentation at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies:

> If you need to use a proxy, you can configure individual requests with the proxies argument to any request method ... [or you can] configure proxies by setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

So if you wanted to not have to switch the proxy, and you have a set proxy at `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, then I would just follow the docs:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:8080"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:8080"

$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://example.org')
```

Of course, setting the envs *can* be done programmatically, but it just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: That is fine. But then what may be the reason for providing `s.proxies.update` method then? N.B. I personally haven't seen the implementation of this method.