# Python Google oauth2 Cannot connect to proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, google-oauth

I have the following code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import requests, json

det_access = json.loads(file)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(det_access['bigquery_creds'])

session = requests.Session()
session.proxies.update(proxies)
session.verify = False

request = Request(session)
credentials.refresh(request)
```

But the above raise the error:

> TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
> at 0x00000251BE1EE2C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))

Do you know how to circumvent the issue please?

Thanks folks!

Comment: have you verified the det_access works and issue is not there? (for instance trying with some different code or by turning off proxy?) have you checked if your http_proxy variable is defined?

Comment: det_access has valid values, no problem with it. I set os[http_proxy] and os[https_proxy] but same error.

Comment: I managed to reproduce your issue partially. In my case the proxies were wrongly configured. Do you have your proxies properly configured? Try a simple example like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839005/12852090 to check the proxy/s are properly configured.

Comment: I do manage to retrieve urls with requests.get(
        url=url, 
        proxies=proxies). So my proxies are correctly set.

Comment: Could you please share the declaration of the proxies so that I can try to better reproduce your issue? Also, as Albert previously suggested, have you tried making the requests without setting up a proxy?